# Some glyphicons are rendered as boxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The bizarre thing is that on the same machine, in the same browser, using the same font files, the same glyphicon renders just fine on a different site that I developed. And that **most glyphicons work on both sites**.

[image: strange glyphicon inconsistency bug]

As you can see, even the relevant CSS code is basically the same (aside from that upper case E when specifying the character which doesn't make a difference).

Thus, it seems to me that all of the common problems like the font being missing/corrupted or the browser being unable to interpret the character code don't apply. What else could cause this?

Comment: Clear your cache.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem was a [corrupt font file](https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff).

I did not use this CDN for my other page and once I used the fonts contained in the Bootstrap Sass npm package instead, the icons showed up.